# Codename one fly over animation

Tags: animation, codenameone

In codenameone, I have two container. One with the several images(source) and another with one image(destination). When i click a button i want the images from source to overlap in the image of destination. I tried using

```
findParentContainer().morphAndWait(findSourceContainer(), findDestinationContainer(),2000);
```

But it removes the destination container from its position then shows it in the destination container and make like the destination container is flying from source to destination.

I also tried by
1. adding another dummy container exactly like source container, alongside the destination container and then make that dummy container but it did not work.
2. also tried to make each individual image to morph but the image just went white after first image.

How can i make the images from source to fly over from their place to the desired contianer?

Answer (score 0):

Components within the container are clipped to its bounds. To move a component from one container to another using an animation you need to create a faux layout within the layered pane and perform the animation there which is neither simple nor trivial.

There are some samples showing animations of this type specifically in the poker and solitaire demos where cards are moved to complex locations. Unfortunately at this time there is no "one size fits all" solution for animating from one Container to another.